# How to fix a null object reference on document snapshot

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an program where the `MainActivity` display the name and the email of the user on top of the screen by using document snapshot that been stored in `firestore` database

However it seems when I press the logout button it invoke this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

This is where the run tap points at this error:

```
DocumentReference docRef = mStore.collection("users").document(userID);
docRef.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Name"));
        email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));

    }
});
```

And this is the full `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseMainMenu {
    private static final String TAG = "TAG";
    private FirebaseAuth mfirebaseauth;
    private String motive[] = {"Once you learn to quit, it becomes a habit","Exercise is labor without weariness"
            ,"A feeble body weakens the mind","Get comfortable with being uncomfortable", "Confidence comes from discipline and training"
            , "Nothing will work unless you do", "All great achievements require time", "Pain is temporary. Quitting lasts forever"
            , "Don’t count the days, make the days count", "Action is the foundational key to all success"
            , "Once you are exercising regularly, the hardest thing is to stop it", "No pain, no gain" };
    TextView name, email, tv1;
    Button b1;


    FirebaseFirestore mStore;
    String userID;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = findViewById(R.id.nname);
        email = findViewById(R.id.eemail);

        mfirebaseauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        userID = mfirebaseauth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        Button logoutt =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
                logoutt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        mfirebaseauth.signOut();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class));
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        DocumentReference docRef = mStore.collection("users").document(userID);
        docRef.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Name"));
                email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));

            }
        });

        Button i1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        i1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, homeorgym.class));
            }
        });

        Button i2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        i2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Features.class));
            }
        });

        Button i3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        i3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, readProfileData.class));


            }
        });

        Button i4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        i4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Meals.class));
            }
        });

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_motive);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_motive);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random random = new Random();
                int num = random.nextInt(motive.length);
                tv1.setText(motive[num]);    }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of firestore firebase document

[image]

Comment: add a condition (!= null) before trying to call methods on it

Comment: @Stultuske can you write the condition ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: You mean a screenshot in firestore ? @AlexMamo

Comment: Yep, a screenshot of your Firestore database.

Comment: if ( documentSnapshot != null ) -> somethinglike this

Comment: I added the screenshot @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

When you add a snapshot listener, you either get a `DocumentSnapshot` or you get a `FirebaseFirestoreException` in the `onEvent` callback. If you *do* get a `FirebaseFirestoreException`, you don't get a `DocumentSnapshot`, which is why you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to use that snapshot.

The solution is to first check whether there is an error, and only access the document once you've determine there is no error:

```
docRef.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Listen failed.", e);
            return;
        }

        if (documentSnapshot != null && documentSnapshot.exists()) {
            name.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Name"));
            email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("email"));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current data: null");
        }
    }
});
```

Once you log the error like this, you can also figure out what the root cause of the problem is and address that.

Also note that the code change I made is quite literally what the Firebase documentation on [reading documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#java) shows, so I recommend keeping that handy.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the second time you helped me and I'm very grateful for your help